# Fill input fields based on URL / BootstrapVue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, bootstrap-vue

I'm using `BootstrapVue`. Now I try to fill my input fields based on my URL..

My code:

```
<template>
  <div class="col-md-6 mt-3">
    <div class="mt-2">ID</div>
    <b-form-input type="number"></b-form-input>
    <div class="mt-2">Name</div>
    <b-form-input type="text"></b-form-input>
  </div>
</template>
```

my `URL: localhost:8080/?UserID=1234&Username=Peter_Parker`

Now it should fill my UserID b-form-input with 1234 and my Username b-form-input with Peter Parker

Is this possible? Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

```
this.$route.query.UserID
```

and

```
this.$route.query.Username
```

Comment: where should I input this code?

Comment: Hey mate, in data function you create properties for id and name, then in template you bind these properties with v-model. In mounted hook you set properties: this.id = this.$route.query.UserID ...